# не подключается к БД SQLSTATE[3D000]

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Перенес сайт с одного хостинга на другой, на первом хостинге была одна БД, а на новом две. подключение к БД происходит, но при запросе к БД выдается эта ошибка:

```
    [host nufypet.kz] Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught 
    PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
     in /var/www/vhosts/alevelcenter.kz/nufypet.kz/func.php:286\nStack 
trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/alevelcenter.kz/nufypet.kz/func.php(286): PDO->prepare('SELECT 
    * FROM u...')\n#1 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/vhosts/alevelcenter.kz
    /nufypet.kz/func.php on line 286\n, referer: http://nufypet.kz/register.php
```

**UPDATE**

исправил вот так, но ошибка осталась:

```
$db = PDO->execute("USE $dbname");
$stmt = $db->prepare(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array('email' => $email));
```

вот так выглядит подключение:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$database= "";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";
$db = new PDO("mysql: dbname =$database; host = $dbhost; charset = utf8",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->exec("set names utf8");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('utf8');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Almaty');
```

Comment: так вам же ошибка говорит в чем проблема - `No database selected`. Укажите, какую именно БД использовать командой `USE database_name;`

Comment: Ну русским же по белому пишут: *No database selected*. Добавьте в код перед любыми обращениями к данным переключение на нужную БД (типа `PDO->execute('USE MyDataBase')`).

Comment: Альтернативно - для каждой таблицы в каждом запросе указывайте алиас схемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я задавался вопросом по этой проблеме и на английском [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Проблема была решена так:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `dbname`.`table` WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");
```

надо было взять в обратные кавычки названия БД и таблиц.
Вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633241/error-acessing-db-sqlstate420001064) на мой вопрос и крайне полезная [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/7830427) по теме.

Answer (score 0):

Там где у вас происходит подключение к базе данных, установите ее название

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

Comment: добавил настройки подключения в вопрос

Comment: и что все ровно выдает туже ошибку ?

Comment: ошибка осталась